# What is the difference between a phone book, a directory, and the yellow pages?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

So, upon looking in a dictionary, this is what I found:

> phone book
> noun [ C ]   informal
> US  /ˈfoʊn ˌbʊk/ UK  /ˈfəʊn ˌbʊk/
> a telephone directory :
> Is he in the phone book?
> (also telephone book, telephone directory)
> a large book containing all the phone numbers for a particular area, organization, etc.

Does this mean personal AND business numbers are included? Compare this with directory:

> Meaning of directory in English :directory
> noun [ C ]
> UK  /dɪˈrek.tər.i/ /daɪˈrek.tər.i/ US  /dɪˈrek.tɚ.i/ /daɪˈrek.tɚ.i/
> C1
> a book that gives a list of names, addresses, or other facts:
> a business directory
> a directory of hotels, Look up their number in the telephone directory.

Okay, that being said, this is the entry for yellow pages:

> Meaning of the Yellow Pages in English
> the Yellow Pages
> noun [ S ]   trademark
> UK  /ˌjel.əʊ ˈpeɪ.dʒɪz/ US  /ˌjel.oʊ ˈpeɪ.dʒɪz/
> a brand name for a large, yellow book that contains the addresses and phone numbers of businesses and people offering services, listing them in groups according to what type of business they are

So, that being said, would it suffice to say that directory and phone book are sort of similar and have both personal and business information and are more general, but the Yellow Pages is strictly businesses and services only? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: In the US, the "phone book" is something that few people use anymore for obvious reasons, but it refers to a physical book of phone numbers.  Historically, there was a "yellow pages" for businesses and "white pages" for individuals.  A "phone book" could be either one of these, or both of them combined (as they sometimes were/are).  A "phone directory" is somewhat more vague - it could really be any list of phone numbers - for example, within a company.  A "directory" (without phone before it) is a still vaguer term for a list (usually organized) of information.

Comment: In the UK 'phone book' is an informal name for what would be more formally described as 'the telephone directory'; however, the much reduced version still issued by British Telecom actually calls itself The Phone Book. It contains both residential and business numbers, but there is also a separate classified business directory printed on yellow paper and called The Yellow Pages in imitation of the American usage. Directories existed before telephones, though, as lists of businesses in a particular town.

Comment: Yes. Yellow pages are just for businesses and are, as mentioned, grouped by type of business. The telephone directory, also called phone book, has an alphabetical list of residential numbers followed by an alphabetical list of business numbers. If you want to speak to the Claremont Hotel you can look under C in the main phone book business section. But if you want to speak to a plumber, but don't know the name of one, look under Plumbers in the yellow pages.

Comment: These further responses remind me that I should add to my answer above: in the US, the white pages indeed include businesses as well as residences.  All are alphabetized by name.  Yellow pages include only businesses, grouped by type of business.

Comment: @KateBunting - the UK Yellow Pages print edition ceased in 2017.

Comment: @cruthers and KateBunting: these seem like substantive answers! (Though, back when we had such things, I was used to my US "white pages" containing only residential listings... I *think*...)

Comment: Since physical phone books are a relic of the past, if someone used these terms these days it would be metaphorical.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone :)